# Parse only specific numbers with Boost.Spirit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

How can I build a Boost.Spirit parser that matches only numbers in a certain range?

Consider the simple parser `qi::uint_`. It matches all unsigned integers. Is it possible to construct a parser that matches the numbers `0` to `12345` but not `12346` and larger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to attach to the `qi::uint_` parser a semantic action that checks the parser's attribute and sets the semantic action's third parameter accordingly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
  qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, unsigned(), qi::ascii::space_type> rule;

  const auto not_greater_than_12345 = [](const unsigned& attr, auto&, bool& pass) {
    pass = !(attr > 12345U);
  };
  rule %= qi::uint_[not_greater_than_12345];

  std::vector<std::string> numbers{"0", "123", "1234", "12345", "12346", "123456"};
  for (const auto& number : numbers) {
    unsigned result;
    auto iter = number.cbegin();
    if (qi::phrase_parse(iter, number.cend(), rule, qi::ascii::space, result) &&
        iter == number.cend()) {
      std::cout << result << '\n';  // 0 123 1234 12345
    }
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Wandbox</kbd>](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ukXT91KU0lrC0y2J)

The semantic action can be written more concisely with [the Phoenix placeholders `_pass` and `_1`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/phoenix.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
  qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, unsigned(), qi::ascii::space_type> rule;

  rule %= qi::uint_[qi::_pass = !(qi::_1 > 12345U)];

  std::vector<std::string> numbers{"0", "123", "1234", "12345", "12346", "123456"};
  for (const auto& number : numbers) {
    unsigned result;
    auto iter = number.cbegin();
    if (qi::phrase_parse(iter, number.cend(), rule, qi::ascii::space, result) &&
        iter == number.cend()) {
      std::cout << result << '\n';  // 0 123 1234 12345
    }
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Wandbox</kbd>](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vnnIhZJO0x1A7EiE)

---

From [Semantic Actions with Parsers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/action.html)

> The possible signatures for functions to be used as semantic actions are:
>
> ```
> ...
> template <typename Attrib, typename Context>
> void fa(Attrib& attr, Context& context, bool& pass);
> ```
>
> ... Here `Attrib` is the attribute type of the parser attached to the semantic action. ... The third parameter, `pass`, can be used by the semantic action to force the associated parser to fail. If `pass` is set to false the action parser will immediately return false as well, while not invoking p and not generating any output.